# Display Math equation from CKeditor5 with WIRISplugin in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, mathml, wiris

I've tried to put `<script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>` in the `<head>` of my index.html using reactjs, however, for some reason this didn't work for me.

**client/public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Portal</title>

    <!-- WIRISplugin -->
    <script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script> 

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the app the math equation remains not displaying and I received on console the 404 error, as the script wasn't able to access the Wiris URL and get the plugin.

*Current results:*

a3xy=∞∅π
21,4 mol ⇄ a∆N

[*Expected results:*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0XnK.png)

Could someone help me? I've read the documentation on the Wiris website (https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_web/integrations/mathml-mode), but I wasn't able to identify why this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the below script to your index.html or the page where you want to render mathml

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

2. Create a new component which will be used to render your math equations

```
function Latex(props) {
  const node = React.createRef();
  const renderMath = () => {
    window.MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', window.MathJax.Hub, node.current]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    renderMath();
  });

  return (
    <div ref={node} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

3. Wrap your content with `<Latex />` component and it will render your equations